# How to fix Left, Mid problems? I get error "Type Mismatch 13" on the line with Left

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I'm reading strings from cells and separate them by the beginning of their name. I'm using Left function and compare it to beginning, but I get

> Error 13 "Type Mismatch"

I found something on the internet and here like VBA `Left(str, 2)` but it doesn't work either.

```
Sub start()

Dim strprj As String
Dim LastRow, radek As Long

LastRow = Worksheets("PROJECT_OFFERSNDA").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For radek = 0 To LastRow - 1
    strprj = Worksheets("PROJECT_OFFERS-NDA").Range("A1").Offset(radek)
    If Left(strprj, 2) = "\\" Then
        MsgBox Str
    End If
Next radek
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `strprj` at the time of error?#

Comment: hi. first change worksheets to sheets and then change the MsgBox Str to MsgBox strprj. good luck

Comment: Check if `strprj` contains a string at the point of error as a type mismatch error would appear to indicate it contains some other data type

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please edit typos, provide sample data and assure the code you have shown produces the error.

Comment: @LuisCurado `Worksheets` is actually preferable to `Sheets` when you are expecting a `Worksheet`. A workbook's `Sheets` collection includes non-worksheet sheets.

Comment: `strprj` is declared `As String`, it cannot possibly contain anything other than a `String`. You're getting the type mismatch error on the `strprj = ...` line, because the cell you're reading contains a cell error; trying to assign a `Variant/Error` into a `String` will always throw a *type mismatch* error. If the string is assigned correctly, then your code can't possibly be blowing up on the `If Left` conditional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get a type mismatch on the `Left` function call with that code, because `strprj` is guaranteed to be a `String`:

```
Dim strprj As String
```

If you're getting a *type mismatch* error, it must be on this line:

```
strprj = Worksheets("PROJECT_OFFERS-NDA").Range("A1").Offset(radek)
```

Because that instruction is reading a `Variant` and implicitly coercing it into a `String` - this may succeed if the cell contains any value that can be represented as a string, or fail with a *type mismatch* otherwise.

That would happen if the cell you're reading from contains an error value, e.g. `#VALUE!`, `#NA`, or `#REF!`.

The solution is to avoid reading cells into anything other than a `Variant`.

```
Dim cellValue As Variant
cellValue = Worksheets("PROJECT_OFFERS-NDA").Range("A1").Offset(radek).Value
```

And then to validate what we're looking at:

```
If Not IsError(cellValue) Then
    strprj = Left(cellValue, 2)
    '...
End If
```

There are other issues:

```
LastRow = Worksheets("PROJECT_OFFERSNDA").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
```

This isn't necessarily reliable. First, you don't want to be dereferencing that sheet every time you need it. Pull it into a local variabel:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PROJECT_OFFERSNDA") '<~ ThisWorkbook? another workbook? Be specific!
```

This is also a potential issue:

```
Dim LastRow, radek As Long
```

`radek` is a `Long` integer, ....and `LastRow` is an implicit `Variant/Empty`. And, you don't need `radek` for another couple of lines, so, declare it when you need it. Getting the last row is usually more reliable with `Range.End`, used from the bottom of the sheet:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim radek As Long '<~ what's wrong with "currentRow"? why "radek"?
For radek = 0 To lastRow - 1
    '...
Next
```

That loop is confusing. `Range.Offset` is confusing. You need to know which row to look at to debug and make sure the data is ok, but nothing in your code points directly to that row number.

```
Dim currentRow As Long
For currentRow = 2 To lastRow

    Dim cellValue As Variant
    cellValue = ws.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value

    If Not IsError(cellValue) Then

        Dim projectPath As String '<~ "strprj" wants more vowels, and "str" prefix is irrelevant!
        projectPath = cellValue

        If Left(projectPath, 2) = "\\" Then
            MsgBox projectPath
        End If

    Else
        Debug.Print "Row " & currentRow & " contains an error, cannot process."
    End If
Next
```